# Adapted width in CSS dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm making a dropdown menu with only CSS, and it's not turning out easy the way I've done it. So far I've got an actual dropdown, but the width is the width of the parent element, which is too small for certain items to be displayed in one line.

[image: Menu width too short]

I tried setting a manual width, but that just unaligns the whole thing and isn't pratical as the menu item could be much longer. Is there anyway of having a width that adapts to the content, without changing the parent width ?

All the site files are located here : http://dev.cuonic.com/bourree/

- Index page : http://dev.cuonic.com/bourree/index.html
- Stylesheet : http://dev.cuonic.com/bourree/css/style.css

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't use a fixed-width for the drop-downs.

First, add the following to the CSS for the links in the drop-downs:

```
#menu ul ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I also had to change `#menu ul` and `#menu ul li` to `#menu > ul` and `#menu > ul > li`, respectively, so that those CSS styles would apply only to the first level menu items.

Here's a basic reference about the use of `>` in CSS selectors.  I think there are other spots in this example where it would help:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector

Comment: I've tried your solution, it worked, I changed the background color and the selectors with the child selectors as you suggested and now the white-space: nowrap; style doesn't seem to have any effect. I've updated the demo site with the changes : http://dev.cuonic.com/bourree/

Comment: Looks like you've spelled it as `white-space: no-wrap`.  Change that to `white-space: nowrap` (no dash) and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Playing around in firefox/firebug I found that this combination seemed to produce the desired effect:

```
#menu ul ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    left: -34px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a possible solution, but I didn't want to set a width manually like that, and when I added a background colour to the sub ul, it got messy, the text and the box are mis-aligned. Thanks anyway :)